# Set svg animate's attribute from css

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG animation, I want to set `animate` tags attribute `from` and `to` using css.

like:

```
animate{
    from: #f7f7f7;
    to: #33d424;
}
```

Is this possible, how can I do that ?

Here is my SVG code:

```
<svg width='100px' height='100px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="uil-squares">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect>
        <rect x="15" y="15" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.0s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="40" y="15" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.125s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="65" y="15" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.25s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="15" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.875s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="65" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.375" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="15" y="65" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.75s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="40" y="65" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.625s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
        <rect x="65" y="65" width="20" height="20" fill="#f7f7f7" class="sq">
            <animate attributeName="fill" from="#f7f7f7" to="#33d424" repeatCount="indefinite" dur="1s" begin="0.5s" values="#33d424;#33d424;#f7f7f7;#f7f7f7" keyTimes="0;0.1;0.2;1"></animate>
        </rect>
    </svg>
```

Comment: It's not possible. Animate attribues are not CSS properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use CSS animations instead of SVG ones. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/scarl3tt/g2frngcn/

```
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    fill: #f7f7f7;
  }
  6.25% {
    fill: #33d424;
  }
  12.5% {
    fill: #f7f7f7;
  }
}
```

You also need to delay each element's animation to make them run in sequence.  I wrote this in pure CSS because I'm not sure how familiar you are with SASS/LESS, but using a preprocessor and an autoprefixer makes this kind of thing a lot easier.